# Pip spitting UnicodeDecode error

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

> I'm not 100% positive as to what is the correct place to post this question since it's 50% programming since it's a python bug and 50% system management, since it's a bug on a package. I went on to post here, If I'm incorrect please direct me to the right place.

I'm currently running Arch Linux 64 bit and earlier today I updated a couple of packages including the (critical I believe) [`python-setuptools`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-setuptools/). Before this `pip` worked perfectly, no issues whatsoever, now however just from running the bare command I get the following:

```
espaco@Arch ~> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3143, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3129, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3156, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 649, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 642, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 698, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2136, in find_on_path
    path_item, entry, metadata, precedence=DEVELOP_DIST
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2518, in from_location
    version = cls._version_from_metadata(dist_path) or version
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2841, in _version_from_metadata
    return _version_from_file(strm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2483, in _version_from_file
    line = next(iter(version_lines), '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 116: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is this something I did wrong or does pip have a bug? How would I be able to fix this?

What I have tried:

- Reinstalling pip
- Reinstalling python-setuptools
- The almighty reboot
- Ask my mom to kiss `bash` in the forehead
- Search the Arch package list for a bug report
- Google the problem

Comment: Why is your first paragraph in a spoiler block?

Comment: Well, technically it's not part of the question, just an addendum in case someone complained about the question; so I 'spoiled' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ll /var/cache/pacman/pkg/python-setuptools-*
```

then select desired version, and

```
$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/python-setuptools-1:18.7-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

where 1:18.7-1 is your previous version of the package

if it will not help:

```
$ cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep 2015-11-30 | grep upgraded
```

and then for each package install it's previous version by doing part 1

you can write a script for that or find existing.

also try to search arch community forums